# SSL error: 'Bad Key Share' error while SSL handshaking

Tags: python, nginx, ssl, gunicorn

I am using python(Django) and my upstream server is Gunicorn and backend server is Nginx. My web app has been delployed since 2021. I applied 'google calendar api' to use calendar to store instance details in google calendar. I tested it in the development environment (local server) and it worked it successfully but when I tested it in the production enviroment, it failed. 502 error. when I checked in the nginx.error.log, it says there:

```
2023/08/12 07:08:15 [crit] 1027#1027: *2547 SSL_do_handshake() failed (SSL: error:0A00006C:SSL routines::bad key share) while SSL handshaking, client: 164.92.248.255, server: 0.0.0.0:4
<2023/08/12 07:32:04 [error] 6129#6129: *1 upstream prematurely closed connection while reading response header from upstream, client: 101.176.222.32, server: easygoshuttle.com.au, requ>
```

I searched and looked all postings but it did not work. I could not find any solution.

Nginx configuration as follows;

````
     server_name easygoshuttle.com.au www.easygoshuttle.com.au ;

     location = /favicon.ico { access_log off ; log_not_found off ; }
     location /static/ {         root /home/ubuntu/github/easygo ;
     }

     location / {
         include proxy_params;
         proxy_send_timeout 10080;
         proxy_read_timeout 10080;
         proxy_connect_timeout 10080s;
         proxy_request_buffering off;
         proxy_buffering off;
         proxy_redirect off;
         proxy_ssl_server_name on;
         proxy_pass http://unix:/run/gunicorn.sock;
     }

    listen 443 ssl http2; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate /etc/letsencrypt/live/easygoshuttle.com.au/fullchain.pem; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_certificate_key /etc/letsencrypt/live/easygoshuttle.com.au/privkey.pem; # managed by Certbot
    include /etc/letsencrypt/options-ssl-nginx.conf; # managed by Certbot
    ssl_dhparam /etc/letsencrypt/ssl-dhparams.pem; # managed by Certbot
}

server {
    if ($host = www.easygoshuttle.com.au) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot


    if ($host = easygoshuttle.com.au) {
        return 301 https://$host$request_uri;
    } # managed by Certbot

     listen 80;
     server_name easygoshuttle.com.au www.easygoshuttle.com.au ;
    return 404; # managed by Certbot
}```
````

Comment: Are you sure these are not two separate errors? They seem to be two lines, and there are 3 IP addresses and the server name that you are trying to connect to.

Comment: Yes, there are two separate errors. First line is actually I did not test it. I just found it in 'nginx.conf', which means someone tried?... I have no idea. Second line is the error message after I tested.

Comment: facing same issue, were you able to fix it ?